# how to update a variable in es6 inside a fetch function?

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, fetch, let

I have this code below:

```
let courses = '';

fetch(link)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
}).then(function(json) {
  courses = json;
}).catch(function(ex) {
  console.log('parsing failed', ex);
});
```

Using `console.log(courses)` prints out ''.

How do I set it to the retrieved json?

Comment: `fetch` is always asynchronous, meaning any synchronous code placed afterwards, will *always* execute before `fetch.then`'s callback is called.

Comment: so, how do I execute those synchronous code after a fetch?

Comment: @JoshuaRajandiran: Just put it in the callback

Comment: You need to understand [how promises work](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). That's why you have all those `.then` chains - to execute code *after* an asynchronous request completes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fetch` method is asynchronous, essentially, you will only have access to the json content in the `courses` variable after the `fetch` [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) resolves. Try doing the following:

```
function synchronousCode(courses) {
  console.log('courses', courses); // output json courses
}

fetch(link)
.then(function(response) {
  return response.json();
})
.then(synchronousCode)
.catch(function(ex) {
  console.log('parsing failed', ex);
});
```

One of the benefits of using the Fetch API is that you can neatly chain your methods instead of just having one "`synchronousCode`" function. Here's an example:

```
function asynchronouslyAnalyze(courses) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () { resolve(courses) }, 1000);
  });
}

function parse(courses) {
  // do something with courses
  return courses;
}

function print(courses) {
  console.log('courses', courses); // output courses json
}

function toJSON(response) {
  return response.json();
}

fetch(link)
.then(toJSON)
.then(asynchronouslyAnalyze)
.then(parse)
.then(print)
.catch(function(ex) {
  console.log('parsing failed', ex);
});
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: `synchronouslyParse` and `synchronouslyConsole` are misnomers…